# bvaughn / react-virtualized : Stop AutoSizer from keep updating the width when browser window resized dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

How do I stop `AutoSizer` from keep updating the width when browser window resized dynamically ( dragged by mouse etc )?

I just need the `width` to calculate once ( on first load ) or when page is refreshed, no more recalculation on screen resize after that

[image]

How do I do that?

```
import {
  List,
  AutoSizer,
  CellMeasurer,
  CellMeasurerCache,
} from "react-virtualized";

function Result(props) {
  ...
  return (
    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
      {({ width }) => {
        containerWidth = width;

        // Get Justified Layout Geometry
        renderJustifiedLayoutGeometry();

        return (
          <React.Fragment
            key={Math.random()
              .toString(36)
              .substr(2, 9)}
          >
            <div className="c-justified-grid" style={{ width: width }}>
              <List
                width={width}
                height={100}
                autoHeight={true}
                rowHeight={rowHeight}
                rowRenderer={renderRow}
                rowCount={new_LayoutGeometry.length}
                style={{ contain: "layout" }}
                overscanRowCount={3}
                key={Math.random()
                  .toString(36)
                  .substr(2, 9)}
              />
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }}
    </AutoSizer>
  );
}
```

Comment: `I just need the width to calculate once ( on first load )` so why not just use vanillajs to do that instead of using a library which goal is to bind and get real time value?

Comment: Can you describe the use case? Why is it preferable to have it only adapt on page load? If the user has a browser window, increases the width, and then refreshes the page, it would suddenly jump to another layout.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in the comments, I first recommends you to see other options as your description seems a bit sketchy and does not make sense. However, if you really like to do that, you can change the code using the following trick, this way, you will only the first width that the component gives you.
Here is how your code should look like:

```js
import {
    List,
    AutoSizer,
    CellMeasurer,
    CellMeasurerCache,
} from "react-virtualized";

function Result(props) {

....
    const [initialWidth, setInitialWidth] = useState(-1);
    return (

        <AutoSizer disableHeight>

            {({ width }) => {
                if(initialWidth === -1){
                     setInitialWidth(width);
                }
                containerWidth = initialWidth;

                // Get Justified Layout Geometry
                renderJustifiedLayoutGeometry();

                return (

                    <React.Fragment key={ Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) }>

                        <div className="c-justified-grid" style={{ width: initialWidth }}>

                            <List
                                width={initialWidth}
                                height={100}
                                autoHeight={true}
                                rowHeight={rowHeight}
                                rowRenderer={renderRow}
                                rowCount={new_LayoutGeometry.length}
                                style={{ contain:'layout' }}
                                overscanRowCount={3}
                                key={ Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) }
                            />

                        </div>

                    </React.Fragment>

                )
            }}
        </AutoSizer>

    );

}
```

I changed a sample code on codesandbox to give you a live example as well, please feel free to have a look and ask question if needed:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-infiniteloader-forked-j6en7p?file=/src/App.js

Hopefully that helps you with what you wanted to achieve.